# How can I push a Git repository to a server where it doesn’t yet exist

Tags: ssh, git

I host my Git repositories at `me@example.com`. So when I want to create a new repository I have to do this:

```
ssh me@example.com
git init --bare ~/git/new_repo.git
exit
git clone me@example.com:git/new_repo
```

This is quite tedious and annoying.

What I would like to do is this (from my local machine):

```
git create_and_clone me@example.com:git/new_repo.git
```

Is there any command that can do this? I could easily write a script but it would be handy if there is a built in 1 liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no command in the git toolkit that does this on a remote host. You could shorten it to:

```
ssh me@example.com 'git init --bare git/new_repo.git'
```